# Missing JFace floating FieldEditor

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I'm porting a large Java application into Eclipse 4.x RCP.  I've been using a variety of JFace classes, especially some of the preference features, instead of the Eclipse or OSGI preference choices.

Why does the JFace PreferenceStore not have a BigDecimal/Decimal/double/float pref?  From the default implemented FieldEditors eclipse.org website:

org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditor

```
org.eclipse.jface.preference.BooleanFieldEditor
org.eclipse.jface.preference.ColorFieldEditor
org.eclipse.jface.preference.ComboFieldEditor
org.eclipse.jface.preference.FontFieldEditor
org.eclipse.jface.preference.ListEditor
    org.eclipse.jface.preference.PathEditor
org.eclipse.jface.preference.RadioGroupFieldEditor
org.eclipse.jface.preference.ScaleFieldEditor
org.eclipse.jface.preference.StringFieldEditor
    org.eclipse.jface.preference.IntegerFieldEditor
    org.eclipse.jface.preference.StringButtonFieldEditor
        org.eclipse.jface.preference.DirectoryFieldEditor
        org.eclipse.jface.preference.FileFieldEditor
```

Do people all hand-code a subclass for doubles?  Is there a commonly used implementation?  Seems like I am missing something...  In my specific case, I need USD $ preferences, like pricing or per-item costs, so I happen to need "$6.99" as a price pref, needing to use an epsilon or precision to 2 base-10 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not the JFace designers so we can't tell you why they didn't do something.

For currency you should stick to `BigDecimal`. `double` and `float` are not suitable for currency - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/2670892).

To store `BigDecimal` as a preference you would have to store it as a `String`. You can extend the `StringFieldEditor` class and override the `doCheckState` method to check that the string is a valid big decimal value.

Comment: Thanks you for the override comment, I eventually found a derived class by Google that handles double as I needed.